# Regexp to extract sources from different video embeds

Tags: php, regex, video

My SMF forum contains posts with video and I want to extract them to show on the Wordpress main page. My current regexp (thanks to SO!) extracts the url of the videos, which I embed using AutoEmbed.

Everything works up until a post looks like this:

```
<embed height="600" width="600" allowscriptaccess="never" quality="high" loop="true" play="true" src="http://mmavlog.net/embed/player.swf?file=http://video.ufc.tv/CSG/UFC113/20100507_ufc113_weigh_in_400k.flv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Here is my current regexp:

```
$regexp = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
```

Since the posts can contain `<embed>` or `<object>` I realize that looking for the url by the "http" might be inaccurate. How can I use the regexp to look for "src=" for `<embed>` and "data=" for `<object>`?

Answer (score 2):

**How not to do it even though it works:**

```
$str = <<<HTML
<object width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
    <embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400">
    </embed>
</object>
HTML;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/(src|value)="([^"]+)"/', $str, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches);
}
// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => value="somefilename.swf"
//             [1] => src="somefilename.swf"
//         )
// 
//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => value
//             [1] => src
//         )
// 
//     [2] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => somefilename.swf
//             [1] => somefilename.swf
//         )
// 
// )
```

**How to really do it:**

This is an example of how to parse HTML with [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), and this is what you should do instead using regular expressions (though you could use any other HTML parser, not strictly `simplehtmldom`, most of them have similar API).

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$str = <<<HTML
<object width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
    <embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400">
    </embed>
</object>
HTML;

$html = str_get_html($str);
$embed = $html->find('embed', 0);
echo $embed->src;
// prints somefilename.swf

$object = $html->find('object param', 0);
echo $object->value;
// prints somefilename.swf
?>
```

Comment: This might be a novice question, by how do I handle the quotes? I have $regexp = '(src|data)="([^"]+)"'

Comment: Here, i expanded a bit on the answer, including the gurun8 and Delan Azabani advices which is really the way you want to go i would expect.

Comment: Awesome, this looks so much easier and effective than the regex. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered parsing the HTML as XML (provided the HTML is well formed) to extract node and attribute data rather than relying on regex?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this process, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Or parse as SGML/HTML5 parser, which is what is meant to parse HTML.

Comment: Hey Ben!  My apologies, I didn't see your comment before.  Here's a PHP XML DOM link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp and this library looks interesting as well: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/  Delan's suggestion could be helpful too.  Delan do you have a helpful link you could recommend?

Comment: Thanks! I will be looking into simplehtmldom for sure!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the regexp:

```
/(?:src|data)="([^"]+)"/
```

A hint: avoid embedding video with `embed` and `object` - that's so 2002. Try using the much simpler and more powerful `video` tag (which requires no plugins).

Comment: Would you rather `no IE support` or `buggy, insecure and non-futureproofed technology`? ;)

Comment: Ha, nice response, but since 60%+ of the users are IE, I'm stuck until an update.